# How to Change datatable default empty table message

Tags: datatables

I am using datatable to list and sort the results.

This is how i initialized datatable

`$('#example1').DataTable({bFilter: false, bInfo: false, paging: false});`

It works fine. But i need to change the default table empty message `No data available in table` to `No records found`. Please help.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": "My Custom Message On Empty Table"
    }
});
```

Reference: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2327/how-to-localize-the-string-no-data-available-in-table

Answer (score 29):

The [answer by Ajinkya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31983571/3534) should still work because the library currently maintains backward compatibility with the old option format, but with more recent versions of the DataTables library (1.10+) you should use:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "language": {
      "emptyTable": "No data available in table"
    }
} );
```

See: https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.emptyTable

Also, if you want to customize the info line when the table (or search results are empty):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "language": {
    "infoEmpty": "No entries to show"
  }
} );
```

See: https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.infoEmpty

Comment: Actually with the new API it should be `$('#example').DataTable(...)` with a capital D in DataTable.

Comment: The difference between `.dataTable` and `.DataTable` is that the former returns a jQuery object (the <=1.9 version style) and the latter returns a DataTables API instance. According to the docs both of these methods will be available in future versions 1.10+.

The naming referred to above was for options; the new camelCase versus the old Hungarian Notation naming convention. The latter will be deprecated in the next major version (2.x) . Although the docs do note that there is plenty of life left in the 1.x version and 2.x is not planned for a long time to come.

Comment: The above is covered in the guide to converting to 1.10 here: https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert    

The decision to use `.dataTable` vs `.DataTable` likely comes down to how greenfield your project is. If you're writing new code go with .DataTable and use the API Instance. If you're working with old code (that uses the jQuery object and Hungarian Notation naming for options) you may want to update just the option naming to save pain later, even though that pain will not likely be experienced until a much later date (i.e. when v2.x is released)

Answer (score 0):

Change the default message for empty results in a DataTable on the fly:

```
    $("#myTable").on('draw.dt', function(){
        $('#myTable .dataTables_empty').html('Your custom message here.');
    });
```

No need for `destroy()` and re-initialization, and you can even change the message based upon another page element.