# How to Change datatable default empty table message with DTOptions?

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I saw many question like this

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983492/how-to-change-datatable-default-empty-table-message),

but all the solutions are using jquery, while i'm trying to figure out how it is possibile using DTOptions

My code at this point is like this :

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withDisplayLength(10)
            .withOption('bFilter', false)
            .withOption('bProcessing', false)
            .withOption('sScrollY', "300px")
            .withOption('sScrollX', false)
            .withOption('bPaginate', false);
```

and my html :

```
<table id="newFornitures" class="table" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions">
```

And I'm searching on a way to add option on `$scope.dtOptions` that overrides the default message of dataTable

Edit:
As I said, i'm not interested in jquery solutions

Comment: do you have any code to show ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom loading in Angular Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103524/custom-loading-in-angular-datatables)

Comment: @Rahul i added some code

Comment: try ` .withLanguage({
            "sEmptyTable":     "Empty"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withDisplayLength(10)
            .withOption('bFilter', false)
            .withOption('bProcessing', false)
            .withOption('sScrollY', "300px")
            .withOption('sScrollX', false)
            .withOption('bPaginate', false)
            .withLanguage({"sEmptyTable":"Empty"})
```