# How to show custom message in datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have dataTable, i need to display custom error message when there is no data.
If success message added records are not binding.
When datatable "zeroRecords": "", custom message should display, not to effect actual functionality

```
table = $('#operator-datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        searching: false,
        stateSave: boolstatus,
        ajax: {
            url: _API.apiBaseUrl + 'OperatorManage/Operator/List',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: _API.headers,
            "dataSrc":"tableData",
            data: function (d) {
                d.columns[0].search.value = $('#bankernumber').val();
                d.columns[6].search.value = $('#branchnumber').val();
                d.columns[4].search.value = $('#revokestatus').val();
                d.columns[2].search.value = $('#operatorjurisdictiontype').val();
            },
            success: function (res) {
                $('.dataTables_processing').hide();
                //var response = JSON.parse(res);
                console.log(res);
                alert("hi");
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                _API.alertAjaxError(xhr);
                $('.dataTables_processing').hide();
            },
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'bankernumber' },
            { data: 'bankername' },
            { data: 'jurisdictiontype' },
```

Comment: is this something are you looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983492/how-to-change-datatable-default-empty-table-message

Comment: Your problem is the use of the `success` handler - use the `dataSrc` or `complete` callback instead.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [DataTable docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.zeroRecords), add this code:

```
table = $("#operator-datatable").DataTable({
    "language": {
        "zeroRecords": "Custom error message goes here"
    }
    //Rest of your code
})
```